# How to return value from scheduler

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I would like to update a value (used later) periodically inside akka http server, the only way i found is to use a scheduler, but i'm not able to return a value from that.

i tried with akka scheduler, i should maybe use Future but don't see how.

The point is to not restart the http server when the value is updated

```
def initializeWebServer(interface : String, port : Int) = {

system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 10 seconds){
 val result = /***/
}


val route: Route =
  concat(
    get{
      path("getResult"){
        complete(result)
      }
    }
  )

val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, interface, port.toInt)
println(s"Server online at http://$interface:$port/")

CoordinatedShutdown(system).addJvmShutdownHook({
  bindingFuture
    .flatMap(_.unbind())
})


}
```

What i would like is something like :

```
val result = schedule( 10 sec){do something and return result}
```

Comment: Just think about this again... You want a scheduler to do something `A` periodically... which means that this thing will be repeated multiple times... Now if this something computes a value that means that the code `B` which uses this value also needs to run periodically. Other way is to periodically update some already existing value.

Comment: Yes, update a value periodicaly and use this value outside is what i would like
The problem is that i do not want to restart the server when the value is updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
var result = 0
val cancellable = scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 10.seconds) {
  result = result + 1
}
```

You can use the `cancellable` value to stop the schedule when it is no longer needed.

---

Here is the full code:

```
def initializeWebServer(interface: String, port: Int) = {

  var result = 0
  val canceallable = context.system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 10.seconds) {
    result = result + 1
  }

  val route: Route =
    concat(
      get {
        path("getResult") {
          complete(result)
        }
      }
    )

  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, interface, port.toInt)
  println(s"Server online at http://$interface:$port/")

  CoordinatedShutdown(system).addJvmShutdownHook({
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind())
  })
}
```

Comment: No sorry, i would like to use the result outside of the scheduler. With your solution i'm not able to use updated result outside

Comment: It works though requires some synchronization. `result` should be at least `volatile`

Comment: @pksimba Can you explain what you meant by "outside"? You can access `result` in the `complete` call in your route, so where else do you want to access it from?

Comment: @simpadjo I don't really understand , can you provide some details please ?

Comment: @Tim the complete is outside the scheduler, and your method does not return the updated result

Comment: I've posted the code in context to show how it would work.

Comment: @Tim, try with `  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var result = 0
    val cancellable = system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 2.seconds) {
      result = result + 1
    }
    println(result)
  }`

Comment: That will probably print `0` or possibly `1`, what are you expecting it to print?

Comment: Sorry @Tim, my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You could model this by using an actor:

```
class StateHolder extends Actor {

  val state = ???

  context.system.scheduler.schedule(0.second, 10.second, self, DoTask)

  def receive = {
    case DoTask   => /* update state */
    case GetState => /* fetch state */
  }
}
```

The `scheduler` will cause the actor to send itself an `DoTask` message and then you can fetch the current state by sending a message.

Comment: Can you give some details about how i can use this kind of class please ?